# How to check if gets.chomp is empty with ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this exercise where I must use a while loop to ask for info to the user and push it to an empty array. When the user doesn't write anything then the while loops stops.

I've tried setting the condition of the while loop with "" or empty? but nothing works.  at this point I'm not sure if the problem is in the condition or the entire while loop

Help please

````
  student_list = []

  puts "add  students to the wagon"
  student = gets.chomp


while student.empty?

  puts "add more students to the wagon"
  student = gets.chomp

  student_list << student


end
```
````

Comment: Do it in stages.  `while student = gets do...` and `chomp` only if you got into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `until`. Refer the following program

```
student_list = []

puts "add  students to the wagon"
student = gets.chomp

until student.strip.empty?
  puts "add more students to the wagon"
  student = gets.chomp
  student_list << student
end
```

Output

```
one
add more students to the wagon
two
add more students to the wagon
three
add more students to the wagon
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
student_list = []

puts "add a student to the wagon"
student = gets.chomp

while !student.empty?
  student_list << student

  puts "add one more student to the wagon"
  student = gets.chomp
end
```

1. you start by reading the first name and assign it to `student`
2. the `while` loop checks that `student` is *not* empty (hence the `!` to invert the condition)
3. within the loop, you add `student` to the array
4. you read the next name and assign it to `student` (overwriting the previous value)
5. end of loop, move up to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using infinite loop and breaking:

```
student_list = []

while true
  str = " more" if student_list.any?
  puts "add#{str} students to the wagon"
  student = gets.chomp
  break if student.empty?
  student_list << student
end
```

Instead of `while true` you can just use `loop do`, but this is beyond the assignment request.

Comment: `student_list.any? ? str = " more" : str = ""` could be better written as `str = "more" if student_list.any?`. local variable `str` would be initialized as `nil` by the parser and interpolation will handle `nil` just fine

Comment: @engineersmnky, yup!